# Stop double loading of cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, locking

Given this code that loads all available languages from the database (just used as an example):

```
/// <summary>
/// Dictionary of all languages
/// </summary>
private static Dictionary<int, Language> GetLanguagesDictionary()
{
    const string cacheIndex = Settings.CachePrefix + "LanguagesDictionary";
    var context = HttpContext.Current;
    if (context.Cache[cacheIndex] == null)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<int, Language>();
        using (var db = new DBContext())
        {
            var q = db.Languages;
            foreach (var rec in q)
            {
                dict.Add(rec.ID, new Language(rec));
            }
        }
        context.Cache.Add(cacheIndex, dict, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
    }
    return (Dictionary<int, Language>) context.Cache[cacheIndex];
}
```

If the code to load the records into the cache takes a while to complete and another page request comes in, it throws exceptions and causes some problems.

What's the best way to modify the above code to make it safe against this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the `lock` to synchronize the write and the createion of your cache as:

```
///
/// for locking synhronize
///
private static readonly object syncLock = new object();

/// <summary>
/// Dictionary of all languages
/// </summary>
private static Dictionary<int, Language> GetLanguagesDictionary()
{
    const string cacheIndex = Settings.CachePrefix + "LanguagesDictionary";
    var context = HttpContext.Current;

    if (context.Cache[cacheIndex] == null)
    {
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            if (context.Cache[cacheIndex] == null)
            {
                var dict = new Dictionary<int, Language>();
                using (var db = new DBContext())
                {
                    var q = db.Languages;
                    foreach (var rec in q)
                    {
                        dict.Add(rec.ID, new Language(rec));
                    }
                }
                context.Cache.Add(cacheIndex, dict, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
            }
        }
    }
    return (Dictionary<int, Language>)context.Cache[cacheIndex];
}
```

Comment: @downvoter can you please care to explain why the -1 ?

Comment: I think this is what I'm after!  Will accept when I read a bit more about it and the other answers

Comment: @TomGullen yes this is the solution... always use lock for static data when you access them from non synhronize code...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Lazy<T>`

```
static Lazy<Dictionary<int, Language>> GetLanguage = 
      new Lazy<Dictionary<int, Language>>(() => GetLanguagesDictionary(), true);
```

Now You will use `GetLanguage.Value` in your code..

**UPDATE**

Your final code would be similar to this:

```
private static Dictionary<int, Language> GetLanguagesDictionary()
{
        var dict = new Dictionary<int, Language>();
        using (var db = new DBContext())
        {
            var q = db.Languages;
            foreach (var rec in q)
            {
                dict.Add(rec.ID, new Language(rec));
            }
        }
        return dict;
}

public static Lazy<Dictionary<int, Language>> GetLanguages = 
    new Lazy<Dictionary<int, Language>>(() => GetLanguagesDictionary(), true);
```

Comment: I've not used lazy before, but the code I supplied is lazy loaded by design.  Will using lazy offer any benefit?

Comment: @TomGullen its `.Value` method is thread safe. The first thread accessing `Value` starts the operation and all other threads(accessing `Value`) wait until the `Value` is available

Comment: @TomGullen That way, You don't also need *context.Cache* or other null checks. Just create the dictionary,fill it and return it. if you make `GetLanguage` public you can access it everywhere.

Comment: ah got you, that is useful!

Comment: @TomGullen BTW: Don't forget, In your current code, you have many copies of it, since you store it in *HttpContext.Current*